# Can making API calls and Database queries cause a bottleneck? Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

Frontend is React and Backend in Node.js.

Currently storing unregistered user carts in MongoDB using sessions (express-session and connect-mongo)

Now in the frontend, I'm making an API call every time a page loads to keep the mini cart on the top right updated. So basically every navbar rerender I'm making a call to the backend and querying to session in the database.

Is this the correct way of doing things or will this cause some stress on the backend since its been queried so much?

I'm still new to API call and database query costs etc. I just want this to cause a bottleneck.

Comment: I would go for storing the cart data of unregistered users in localStorage, then push it to the database after signup. If you were to store the cart data directly in the database, you won't be able to tell which cart belongs to which user since you don't have the users' details yet in the database.

Comment: @Tunmee I was thinking of creating a separate cart table for unregistered users and sorting their data there. Purge the table after 7 days or so or if they register then they will be added to their own registered user cart table. This way I can track abandoned cart and have some better analytics.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if it's stateless or not. If it is we need to make continuous requests to the API, otherwise we can skip this step.